# Firestore in cloud function takes a few minutes to initialize and make first requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

For this simple Firestore query run on Cloud Function, it always takes a long time if we haven't call it for a while and need to create a new client connection (longest ever been was 100+ seconds)

Below is the minimum reproducible `index.ts` and detailed log. I tried using both `admin.firestore()` and `new Firestore({ grpc })` and got similar result.

```
import {https, config} from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
const { Firestore } = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const grpc = require('@grpc/grpc-js');

let initialized = false;

exports.timeQuery = https.onRequest(async (req:any, res) => {
        res.json({received: true});

    if (!initialized) {
      admin.initializeApp(config().firebase);
      admin.firestore.setLogFunction(console.log);
      initialized = true;
    }
    // using gRPC
    console.log('using gRPC via @google-cloud/firestore')
    const db = new Firestore({ grpc });
    // using admin node SDK
    // const db = admin.firestore();

    await db.collection("debugCollection")
        .doc("debug")
        .get();
    }
  );
```

I enabled debug logging in Firestore and found it took 47 seconds to initialized Firestore GAPIC Client.

```
Firestore (3.7.5) 2020-05-04T20:37:23.541Z ##### [Firestore]: Initialized Firestore GAPIC Client
  1:36:36.054 PM
  timeQuery
  Firestore (3.7.5) 2020-05-04T20:36:36.054Z peRnr [ClientPool.acquire]: Creating a new client
```

and between sending requests and receiving query response, it took another 35 seconds.

```
Firestore (3.7.5) 2020-05-04T20:38:00.139Z peRnr [Firestore.requestStream]: Received response: {"transaction":{"type":"Buffer","data":[]},"readTime":{"seconds":"1588624676","nanos":86619000},"missing":"projects/xxxxxxxx-my-project-id/databases/(default)/documents/debugCollection/debug","result":"missing"}
  1:37:25.141 PM
  timeQuery
  Firestore (3.7.5) 2020-05-04T20:37:25.141Z peRnr [Firestore.requestStream]: Sending request: {"database":"projects/xxxxxxxx-my-project-id/databases/(default)","documents":["projects/xxxxxxxx-my-project-id/databases/(default)/documents/debugCollection/debug"]}
```

Here is the details logs.

```
  1:38:05.440 PM
  timeQuery
  Firestore (3.7.5) 2020-05-04T20:38:05.440Z peRnr [Firestore.getAll_]: Received 1 results
  1:38:05.240 PM
  timeQuery
  Firestore (3.7.5) 2020-05-04T20:38:05.240Z peRnr [Firestore._initializeStream]: Received stream end
  1:38:00.340 PM
  timeQuery
  Firestore (3.7.5) 2020-05-04T20:38:00.340Z peRnr [Firestore.getAll_]: Document missing: projects/xxxxxxxx-my-project-id/databases/(default)/documents/debugCollection/debug
  1:38:00.141 PM
  timeQuery
  Firestore (3.7.5) 2020-05-04T20:38:00.140Z peRnr [Firestore._initializeStream]: Releasing stream
  1:38:00.141 PM
  timeQuery
  Firestore (3.7.5) 2020-05-04T20:38:00.139Z peRnr [Firestore.requestStream]: Received response: {"transaction":{"type":"Buffer","data":[]},"readTime":{"seconds":"1588624676","nanos":86619000},"missing":"projects/lovecaster-staging/databases/(default)/documents/debugCollection/debug","result":"missing"}
  1:37:25.141 PM
  timeQuery
  Firestore (3.7.5) 2020-05-04T20:37:25.141Z peRnr [Firestore.requestStream]: Sending request: {"database":"projects/xxxxxxxx-my-project-id/databases/(default)","documents":["projects/xxxxxxxx-my-project-id/databases/(default)/documents/debugCollection/debug"]}
  1:37:25.140 PM
  timeQuery
  Firestore (3.7.5) 2020-05-04T20:37:25.140Z peRnr [ClientPool.acquire]: Re-using existing client with 100 remaining operations
  1:37:24.440 PM
  timeQuery
  Firestore (3.7.5) 2020-05-04T20:37:24.440Z ##### [Firestore.initializeIfNeeded]: Detected project ID: xxxxxxxxxxx-my-projectID
  1:37:23.541 PM
  timeQuery
  Firestore (3.7.5) 2020-05-04T20:37:23.541Z ##### [Firestore]: Initialized Firestore GAPIC Client
  1:36:36.054 PM
  timeQuery
  Firestore (3.7.5) 2020-05-04T20:36:36.054Z peRnr [ClientPool.acquire]: Creating a new client
  1:36:36.052 PM
  timeQuery
  Firestore (3.7.5) 2020-05-04T20:36:36.051Z ##### [Firestore]: Initialized Firestore
  1:36:36.050 PM
  timeQuery
  using gRPC via @google-cloud/firestore
  1:36:36.043 PM
  timeQuery
  Function execution took 54 ms, finished with status code: 200
  1:36:35.989 PM
  timeQuery
  Function execution started
```

And node package versions: 
`"firebase-admin": "^8.11.0", "@grpc/grpc-js": "0.8.1",  "@google-cloud/firestore": "3.7.5",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is behaving this way because you're sending the response before all the work is complete.  According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions), the function is terminated immediately after the response is sent.  Any other work after that might not finish correctly.  So, your call to `res.json({received: true});` should be the very **last** thing in the function.

If you want your function to instead send a response immediately to the client, and continue to do work outside of that, you will not be able to do that with a single HTTP function.  You will instead have to offload that work to another service or function.  It's common to send a message to a [pubsub function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events) to have it pick up in the background where the first function left off.

Comment: Thanks Doug! We moved the res.send() to the end and it solved the issue.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  The convention on Stack Overflow is to upvote and mark answers as correct if they were helpful - please use the buttons on the right of this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Upvoted (though may not be shown since I don't have enough reputation) and accepted the answer.